# Populate combobox based on selection in another combobox in wordpress

Tags: ajax, combobox, wordpress

I want to populate combobox based on selection in another combobox in wordpress template. the options of combobox are from database. I use AJAX for get the data from combobox1 then it send to help.php. In help.php, there is a query to populate options then displayed in combobox2. But, when I select option in combobox1, combobox2 is not respond. Besides the ID from combobox1 is successfully sent. Then I realized, that the query is not executed. I think this script below

```
global $wpdb
```

is the main problem. So this is the question:
1. How to make global $wpdb executed?
2. If global $wpdb successfully executed, will combobox2 populate automatically?

here are the form script

```
<form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="200px">
                <select name="region" id="region" style="width:200px;">
                    <option value="0">-- Choose --</option>
                    <!-- region -->
                    <?php 
                    if(count( $region )){
                        foreach($region as $reg){
                            echo '<option value='.$reg->id_region.'" >'.$reg->name_region.'</option>';
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo '<option value="">No result</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
                <td width="200px"><select name="subregion" id="subregion" style="width:200px;">
                    <option value="0">-- Choose --</option> 
                </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Process" class="button" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and here is the AJAX

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" >      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#region").change(function(){
        var region = $("#region").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/help.php" ,
            data: "region=" + region,
            success: function(data){
                $("#subregion").html(data);
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

and here is the help.php

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$sub = $_REQUEST['region'];
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sub_region';
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id_region='$sub' ";
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( $query);

if(count($sql)){
    foreach( $sql as $q ){
        echo '<option value="'.$q->id_sub_region.'" >'.$q->name_sub_region.'</option>';
    }
} else{
    echo '<option value="0">-- No Result --</option>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `require_once('../../../wp-load.php');` at the beginning of file in help.php(before global $wpdb;).
 This loads all the wordpress built in functions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the built in WordPress AJAX functionality.

I believe the best way to do it is like so: *(not using wp-load.php)*

```
function enqueue_scripts_styles_init() {

    // ajax init
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-handle-name', plugins_url( '/js/the-ajax.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), 1.0 );
    // set ajaxurl
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-handle-name', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}
add_action('init', 'enqueue_scripts_styles_init');
```

This is how I use it in plugins. To use in themes, just change the plugins url to template or stylesheet directory and drop this in your functions.php file.

- Read about AJAX in WordPress:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX
- Read about AJAX in WordPress plugins:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins